# Why is my Jupyter Notebook using ascii codec even on Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, jupyter-notebook, save, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm analyzing a dataframe that contains French characters.

I set up an IPython kernel based on **Python3** within my jupyter notebook, so the default encoding should be **utf-8.**

However, I can no longer save my notebook as soon as an accented character appears in my .ipynb (like é, è...), even though those are handled in utf-8.
The error message that I'm getting when trying to save is this :

> Unexpected error while saving file: Videos.ipynb 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 347-348: ordinal not in range(128)

Here is some minimal code that gives me the same error message in a basic Python3 kernel

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'EN': ['Hey', 'Wassup'], 'FR': ['Hé', 'ça va']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

(actually a simple cell with "é" as text does prevent me from saving already)

I've seen similar questions, but all of them were based on Python 2.7 so nothing relevant. I also tried several things in order to fix this :

- Including `# coding: utf-8` at the top of my notebook
- Specifying the utf-8 encoding when reading the csv file
- Trying to read the file with latin-1 encoding then saving (still not
  supported by ascii codec)
- Also checked my default encoding in python3, just to make sure

  `sys.getdefaultencoding()
  'utf-8'`
- Opened the .ipynb in Notepad++ : the encoding is set to utf-8 in there. I can add accented characters and save there, but then can no longer open the notebook in jupyter (I get an "unknown error" message").

The problem comes from saving the notebook and not reading the file, so basically I want to switch to utf-8 encoding for saving my .ipynb files but don't know where.

I suspect the issue might come from the fact that I'm using WSL on Windows10 - just a gut feeling though.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, turns out uninstalling then reinstalling jupyter notebook did the trick. Not sure what happened but it's now solved.